# How to add JOptionPane when you press Agree

Tags: java, dialog

I Want to create a custom jOptionPane without YES/NO but AGREE/DISAGREE.
When I press Agree I'd like to have a showMessageDialog box.
Can you help me, please?

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   String[] options = new String[2];
   options[0] = "Agree";
   options[1] = "DISAGREE";
   JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame.getContentPane(),"Would you like to 
   continue?","Message", 
   0,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null,options,null);
```

Comment: It looks like you have a good start.  What problems are you having?

Comment: You might also want to look at [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be helpful for you.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   String[] options = new String[2];
   options[0] = "Agree";
   options[1] = "DISAGREE";
 int result=  JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame.getContentPane(),"Would you like to continue?","Message", 
   0,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null,options,null);

 if(result==1){//when disagree
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Disagree!");

 }else if(result==0){//when agree
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Agree!");  
 }
```